# Merge node in activity diagram

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I'm learning Activity diagram in UML and now I'm confused with the following diagram for representing procedures when calling a pizza.[image]

I think a merge node should be added before the join node because if not, the join node will wait forever. Is that correct?
Thank you.

Comment: See also [Conrad Bock, UML 2 Activity and Action Models, Part 3: Control Nodes](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_11/column1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are right.

There should be a merge node merging the two flows coming from the `decision` right after `Ask for toppings` and a merge node to merge the two flows that have been split by the `decision` right after `Deliver Pizza`

A join node will only continue if it gets a token from **all** incoming flows, which will never happen if those flows are mutually exclusive because of a decision earlier on.

Comment: thank you, now I have more confidence because there is someone having same understanding with me for that diagram

Comment: @Geert: Your answer is correct. I had to think about this in terms of tokens before I saw the two problems: those joins require tokens from ALL incoming control flows, which is impossible because some are mutually exclusive. It may be helpful to other readers to add something to that effect.

Comment: @JimL. I added a bit more info to my answer to make point that out.